# Trouble accessing a subclass in HTML from CSS

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="body-2">
  <div class="body-2a">
    <div class="body-2a(a)">
      <p>dark background color (hero and footer)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="body-2a(b)">
      <p>#1F2937</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.body-2 .body-2a .body-2a(b){
}
```

Whenever I try to access the subclass of body-2a(b), my editor will show an error. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Please use `body-2a-a` and `body-2a-b` as class name.

Answer (score 3):

First things first its not a good practice to use class names like this.

You can't access braces () like other class names, but if you really want to use it you can select it by `.body-2a\(b\)`

```css
.body-2 .body-2a .body-2a\(b\){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class ="body-2">
        <div class ="body-2a">
        <div class ="body-2a(a)">
        <p>dark background color (hero and footer)</p>
        </div>
        <div class ="body-2a(b)">
        <p>#1F2937</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```